# How can I prove that a function F isn't a pseudo random function?

Tags: pseudo-random-function

> Let $F$ be a length-preserving pseudorandom function. For the following constructions of a keyed function $F' : \{0, 1\}^n \times \{0, 1\}^{n−1} \to \{0, 1\}^{2n}$, state whether $F'$ is a pseudorandom function. If yes, prove it; if not, show an attack.
>
> $$F'_k(x) = F_k(0 ∥ x) ∥ F_k(1 ∥ x) \tag{a}$$
>
> and
>
> $$F'_k(x) = F_k(0 ∥ x) ∥ F_k(x ∥ 1) \tag{b}$$

I don't want the solution: I want to understand how I can solve this type of exercise.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63366/discussion-on-question-by-thinker-92-how-cab-i-prove-that-a-function-f-isnt-a-p).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your title asks "How to prove that a function F isn't a pseudo random function", in your question case (b) is not PRF which is easy to prove. function $F'$ is PRF if for **all** PPT distingushers $D$, success probability of $D$ distinguishing $F'$ from random function be negligible. So **for proving that function $F'$ is not PRF** it suffices to construct **one** distinguisher (which queries to its oracle and look for non-random patterns) with non-negligible success probability.

In contrast case (a) here is PRF, which is harder to proof. **for proving function $F'$ is PRF** as @fkraiem mentioned suppose $F'$ is not PRF and $D'$ is distinguisher for $F'$ then construct an algorithm $A$ which breaks some assumption (Distingush $F$ from random function here breaks assumption of $F$ being PRF).

Answer (score 7):

The general approach for proving that something is not a PRF is to come up with a distinguisher for it. A general approach for proving that a construction $F'$ from a PRF $F$ is also pseudo-random is to prove the contrapositive. That is we prove the contrapositive of

$F$ is pseudo-random implies $F'$ is pseudo-random

which is

$F'$ is not pseudo-random implies $F$ is not pseudo-random.

This is easier to prove as we assume that there is some distinguisher $D'$ which distinguishes $F'$ from a random oracle, and then prove that this implies there is some distinguisher $D$, distinguishing $F$ from a random oracle. To do this, we can show that if $D$ is playing the PRF game against a challenger who has chosen $F$ or a random oracle, then $D$ may simulate (in a polynomial number of queries to the challenger) the PRF game between $D'$ and a challenger who has chosen $F'$ or a random oracle. You could think of this interaction as though $D$ has $D'$ in it's belly, and uses it to win the PRF game as shown in the picture

[image]

To get an intuitive sens of how this "reduction" would work for this example, imagine that for each query $x_i$ that $D'$ makes, $D$ takes that query and queries the challenger twice (once for $0||x_i$, and once for $1||x$) returning, the concatenation of both of these queries to $D'$. This has effectively made it so that $D$ has returned $F'_k(x_i)$ to $D'$, and in this way simulates that $D'$ is interacting with a challenger for the PRF $F'_k$. Since this simulation was done with a polynomial number of queries (2x as many), if $D$ responds with the same answer that $D'$ produces, it will have the same advantage as $D'$. Thus, if $D'$ has non-negligible advantage, so does, $D$, which is the contrapositive we sought to prove.

Answer (score 1):

A hint for part (a): *If $R(x)$ is a truly random function, then so is $R'(x) = R(0|x) | R(1|x)$*

Now to prove [$F$ pseudorandom $\implies F'$ pseudorandom],

we will prove the contrapositive [$F'$ not pseudorandom $\implies F$ not pseudorandom].

Suppose $F'$ is not pseudorandom. That means there is a distinguisher $D'$ which can guess with a probability higher than $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{p(n)}$ whether it interacts with $F'$ or $R'$. How can you use $D'$ to construct a distinguisher $D$ which would guess with a probability higher than $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{p(n)}$ whether it interacts with $F$ or $R$?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of answers here for part (a) about how to use distinguisher for F' into distinguisher for F. A hint for part b). Suppose we have some $x' \in \{0,1\}^{n-2}$, what do you expect to get for $F'_k(x'||1)$ and $F'_k(0||x')$.