# Why is this function pseudo random (PRF)?

Tags: pseudo-random-function

First, I want to clarify this is not homework. I encountered this question (here [How can I prove that a function F isn't a pseudo random function?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32513/how-to-prove-that-a-function-f-isnt-a-pseudo-random-function/)) while studying for a test coming soon.

1. $F'_k(x) = F_k(0||x) || F_k(1||x)$
2. $F'_k(x) = F_k(0||x) || F_k(x||1)$

(Here $||$ representing concatenation, $F$ is a PRF).

I know that the second function is not a PRF and I came up with an adversary for it by myself.

As for the first fuction, I read comments saying it is a PRF, but I couldn't find a way to **formally prove this**.
I know the method of proving these kinds of questions.

I should assume by contradiction that $F'_K$ is not a PRF, namely it has an adversary $D'$ that distinguishes between $F'_K$ and a random function $f'$ with non-negligible probability.  Using $D'$, I should construct an adversary $D$ that distinguishes between $F_K$ and a random function $f$ with non-negligible probability - which is a contradiction.

I thought of the following reduction for constructing $D$:

Given an input $x$, and a oracle access $O$ (for $F_K$), $D$ runs $D'$ on $O(0||x)||O(1||x)$. Then, $D$ answers what $D'$ answers.

- If $O=F_k$ , then $D$'s probability of distinguishing is equal to $D'$'s.
- If $O=f$ (the random function) - **Well, here I'm stuck.**

Comment: We do answer homework questions if enough has been done to solve it yourself. So although this is not homework, it would be on-topic if it was :)

Comment: Could you explain the distinguisher for 2.? I don't quite see it.

Comment: Find $x \neq y$ such that $0\|x = y \| 1$. Then different outputs of $F'_k$ have halves in common, which shouldn't happen with probability 1.

Comment: @Occams_Trimmer, $D$ the distiguisher: given an oracle access $O$, query $O(0||x)$, $O(1||x)$  and obtain responses $s_1$, $s_2$ respectively. Then $D$ runs $D'$ on  $s_1||s_2$ and answers what $D'$ answers. If $O=F_k$, $D$ runs $D'(F_k(0||x)||F_k(1||x))$, and since $D$ answers what $D'$ answers - they have the same probability to distinguish.  If $O=f$ (the random function), $D$ runs $D'(f(0||x)||f(1||x))$, and as I said, here I'm stuck.  I'm not sure how to prove that $f(0||x)||f(1||x)$ is random (maybe it's not random at all).

Comment: @SamuelNeves, could you elaborate? I don't quite understand.

Comment: @giselle That was a reply to Occams_Trimmer; it's the same as your attack. (1) is indeed secure.

Comment: @SamuelNeves, you're right. I misread Occams_Trimmer' comment (1 instead of 2). I wrote the attack for 1. Do you have any idea how to complete this prove?

Answer (score 6):

This is not exactly the way you're going about it, but I find it an easier way to deal with this kind of construction in general. First we switch to an information-theoretic setting, then go back to the concrete construction. This is very similar to proving the security of counter mode encryption.

First, we replace $F_k$ by a real random function $G$. Every new input to $G$ results in a uniformly random output $G(x) \in \{0,1\}^{n}$. Now we have the corresponding
$$
G'(x) = G(0\|x)\|G(1\|x)\,.
$$
Since every call to $F_k'$ gives you two free calls to $F_k$, we have
$$
\mathbf{Adv}^{\mathrm{prf}}_{F_k'}(D) \le \mathbf{Adv}^{\mathrm{prf}}_{F_k}(D') + |\mathbf{Pr}[D(G') = 1] - \mathbf{Pr}[D(\$) = 1]| \,,
$$
for a distinguisher $D'$ that performs at most $2q$ queries, by the triangle inequality (the first term being $\Delta_D(F_k', G')$, and the second being $\Delta_D(G', \$)$. $\$$ represents the ideal random function).

Our goal now is to distinguish $G'$ from a uniformly random function from $\{0,1\}^{n-1}$ to $\{0,1\}^{2n}$, to determine the second term of the above inequality. Notice that the inputs to $G$ are properly domain-separated: there are never any collisions between $0\|x$ and $1\|x$ for any distinct $x$.

More concretely, take any set of (distinct) queries $((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \dots, (x_q, y_q))$, where $y_i = \mathcal{O}(x_i)$. The probability that $G'(x_1) = y_1$, $G'(x_2) = y_2$, $\dots$, $G'(x_q) = y_q$ is $\left(\frac{1}{2^{n}}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)^q = 2^{-2nq}$. The probability for a random function is also $2^{-2nq}$, as each output has independent probability $2^{-2n}$.

The definition of advantage is
$$
|\mathbf{Pr}[D(F) = 1] - \mathbf{Pr}[D(\$) = 1]|\,,
$$
for any distinguisher $D$. From this we conclude that the advantage of any attacker against $G'$ is $0$, since it has exactly the same probability distribution as the random function. So we conclude that
$$
\mathbf{Adv}^{\mathrm{prf}}_{F_k'}(D) \le \mathbf{Adv}^{\mathrm{prf}}_{F_k}(D') + 0 \,.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Constructing a distinguisher $D$ for $F$ from a distinguisher $D'$ for $F'$. $D$ runs $D'$. When $D'$ asks to call its oracle on a string $x$, $D$ calls its oracle on the strings $0||x$ and $1||x$, concatenates the answers, and gives the resulting string to $D'$ as its answer. Finally $D$ outputs what $D'$ outputs.

It is clear that

- $D$ runs in poly time if $D'$ does;
- if $D$'s oracle implements $F$, its success probability is the same as that of $D'$ when its oracle implements $F'$; and
- if $D$'s oracle implements a random function, its success probability is the same as that of $D'$ when its oracle does likewise.

P.S.: The distinguisher is *not* given any input string, only the security parameter. It chooses input strings according to its definition.